# LightDM configuration unable to set LightDM as default

Tags: login, dpkg, lightdm, gdm

My original problem was when attempting to log in to a new user account via the gui I encountered a black screen which then soon put me back at the login gui. It is probably important to note that other users did not have this problem, they were able to log in with no problems. I found this question which seemed to be my problem, and attempted the solutions provided in the first answer: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop?newreg=eb29ae144e2d479e883d6df9d8c32d95)

I didn't have the first two problems, and so I attempted to reconfigure lightdm with dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

I encountered the Configuring lightdm screen, and seeing no other options I decided to give gdm a shot, selecting it for my default display manager. I rebooted the machine, and then unfortunately even the initial login gui did not show up. So, it seems that something is wrong with gdm. My new goal is to at least get back to being able to see the gui and log in with other users, unfortunately I experience the following error when I attempt to switch to lightdm as the default when using dpkg-reconfigure lightdm:

mv: cannot move '/etc/X11/default-display-manager' to '/etc/X11/default-display-manager.dpkg-tmp': Read-only file system

I could attempt to manually edit the file for default-display-manager, but I think that would probably be going too deep. I need to first understand why dpkg-reconfigure lightdm is not currently functional. What would be a good next step?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the configuration for read-only was due to the fact that I was accessing the terminal through safe mode. After using keyboard shortcuts to access the terminal on the black screen I was able to re-establish LightDM as the default, and get the GUI back